# Telegram bot not sending posts to a group

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, getmethod, osticket

I have a ticketing systems powered by osTicket open source platform. I found a plugin made for odTicket in [Github](https://github.com/drtomasso/osticket-telegram) and it mentioned it can send notification of new tickets to a telegram group or channel.
The process is that I need to create a bot and paste the bot url *with token) and Chat Id.
Here is the documenting of this plugin:

> Clone this repo or download the zip file and place the contents into
> your `include/plugins` folder. Insert Telegrams Bot URL for your bot
> (ex. `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/`) and Chat ID.

I created a bot and connceted to a group. the bot urls is:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>
```

and group Id:

```
osticketchat
```

Howeverm I don't get any notification in my telegram when posing a new ticket.
When I paste the bot url in browser I get:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
```

I'm not a developer, so I;m not sure if the url is correct or not (I'm sure about the token). Somewhere I read I can add getMe method at the end of url to check if it's working and when I did I get the following message :

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":1672003338,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"osTicket Notification","username":"rafieeticketbot","can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":false,"supports_inline_queries":false}}
```

The ticketing website is :

```
https://help.rafiee.net
```

I would be so grateful if someone can help me know what is wrong to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found the problem.
First, I need to add the bot to the group or channel.
Second, group or channel chat id can be gotten by adding `getUpdates` at the end of url.
And finally, I need an edit in Telegrambot.php line 35 by adding a negative sign (-) before $chatid since chat id of group and channels in telegram is negative.